# Muphen64Plus FZ and generic N64 USB controller issues

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-64

I tried to map my USB N64 controller to Muphen64plus FZ but the controller doesn't even show up on the emulator. it shows up as a generic joystick controller on my windows 10 computer and I ran the tests on it so I know the controller that I recently purchased from Amazon works. I have searched all over the Web, YouTube, and other Forums but all I found was info on USB adapters, mapping problems and other issues. I have tried everything I can think of to fix it on my own.

Is there some kind of plugin that I need for Muphen to get it to recognize the controller?

Has or is anyone else having/had this experience?

Any help would be appreciated, as this is extremely frustrating.